# Finding max value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've searched on here and tried a few of the different methods but not getting the desired results.  I have an array of 30 elements.  I'm trying to loop through a javascript array and find the min and max values.  Problem is that i'm only getting the last value of the array.  I've tried using Math.max.apply and still get 90  the largest number in the array is 97 but 90 appears 4 times and the last time a the very end of the array also.

Here is the code

```
            var max = 0;
        var min = 0;
        var len = weather.length;
        var temps;

        for(i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            temps = weather[i].MaxTemp;
            max = Math.max(temps, len);
            //max = Math.max(weather[i].MaxTemp, len);
        }
        console.log(max);
```

Comment: `len` is not an element of the array. I suggest that you learn how to debug your JavaScript code.

Comment: Read the code out loud!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean

```
max = Math.max(temps, max);
```

You need to compare the current element to the previously found max. If your temps are all negative, you'll have a problem. So you want

```
var max = -99999;
```

as well.